# Options for running GAMs with excessive zeros

Tags: r, count-data, generalized-additive-model

I am analyzing count data that has 75% zeros, and I want to determine how catch of my species of interest has changed over time. Since I am looking at a 30 year time series I am using a smoother for year, and was able to run poisson and negative binomial models with the gam function in mgcv, as well as a zero-inflated poisson GAM using the ziP family.

I believe for several reasons that a hurdle model would be a better fit for my data, but there is no zero-truncated poisson or negbin family option within mgcv. I know glmmTMB has those families, but it seems like that package does not support smoothers. I've come across the brms package, but it is quite complex and very slow, and I only have a surface level knowledge of Bayesian stats. Are there any other options for dealing with excessive zeros in a GAM context without resorting to computationally intensive Bayesian methods? Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest looking at the prophet package. It might meet your needs. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prophet/prophet.pdf. This is also kind of a statistics question. I would suggest you ask this on Cross Validated as well.

Comment: Prophet is for *forecasting* and will not be useful at all here. CrossValidated is definitely the right place to ask.

Comment: Did you check the [`VGAM` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=VGAM)? According to this [overview vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdf) from the `pscl` package, the `VGAM` package calls hurdle models "zero-altered models" with functions like `zapoissonff()` and `zanegbinomial()` for fitting. I have no experience with GAMs or hurdle models, however, and I don't know about whether `VGAM` handles smoothers.